WiX v5: Install driver using dpinst
I have looked through similar questions on the forum and have found no solution to my problem.
I am trying to call dpinst using a custom action and get the error: "Error 1721. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run."
The dpinst executable is installed properly and in the correct location.
Here is my code for the custom action:
<CustomAction Id="LaunchDPInst" 
                  Directory="DRIVERS"
                  ExeCommand='"[DRIVERS]dpinst64.exe" /SW'
                  Execute="deferred" 
                  Return="check" 
                  Impersonate="no"/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
   <Custom Action="LaunchDPInst" After="InstallFiles"></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>

I have also tried with Execute="immediate" and Impersonate="yes"

I would check the public Drivers property getting resolved to the correct path, also I would change the directory attribute to a system property like system64 finally check if utility architecture matches OS architecture for example (AMD 64 bit). Check the 5 lines above the error you listed in the instruction log file for some of the above information. Hope that will help.
